# What is most efficient way of writing on an index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am currently designing index architecture and index patterns. Is it advisable to write on an index for 30 days? I am doing a namespace level indexing hence the traffic in the namespace is very fewer Elasticsearch documents suggests having shard's size of 20-50GB. It would take around 30 days for the index to reach this mark. Is this advisable?

Comment: "It would take around 30 days for the index to reach this mark" - how much data are you indexing, exactly?

Comment: @Dai [From the context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#shard-size-recommendation) it's obviously 50GB and not 50Gb or 50GiB

Comment: @Val aye, I've been spending too much time on low-level electronics lately...

Comment: @Dai I hear ya :-)

Comment: 50GB my bad for the misleading question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have time-based data, the [official recommendation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#use-ds-ilm-for-time-series) is to keep writing your documents to time-based indexes up to a certain size ([between 10GB and 50GB](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#shard-size-recommendation)) and then have [Index Lifecycle Management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) roll over to new a new index once the index reaches that size.

The new way of dealing with time series data is to leverage [data streams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-streams.html) which handle all the nitty gritty details of creating new indices, rolling over to them and provide a high-level read access to all the underlying historical indexes.

Comment: As the traffic in my namespace is low it would take more than 15days to reach an index size of 10Gb or something above that mark. Would this affect elastic's query performance? In my current architecture, we have rollover if primary shards cross 50GB and the max days to write on an index is 5.

Comment: Absolutely not, the whole point is to not create too many too small indices. So I guess max_days in your case could be higher, more towards 30 days

Comment: I was trying to implement a datastream but am not getting the result now when I mention a condition in ingest node its not indexing like how I want to

Comment: Can you describe your problem in a new question since this one is solved?

Comment: no this one I am trying to implement but getting the other error. i will post the question soon here

Comment: This one was more conceptual, your new issue seems specific to data streams

Comment: yes its more towards datastreams/index template and ingest node